# Changed seattle.html - now I cannot access the site at all via web

Tags: master-page, page-layout

I modified `seattle.html` - all other users can view the SP site as normal, but I cannot access it. It gives me an error message:

> Sorry, something went wrong. Don't worry. We're working hard to get this fixed. Please try again later

with the Correlation ID: fdfeab9c-2066-1000-72ef-0ec887c0549b.

However, I can access the mobile version, so it seems. Somehow my `seattle.html` that was uploaded is corrupt, another admin has uploaded the backup of `seattle.html`. However I cannot access the site, and we can't figure out why. Any ideas how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: could you please check the ULS logs for more details about the error....you already have the correlation id...use Smerge-splogfile to get complete trace.

Comment: I don't have access to them, this is Sharepoint 365.